# video compressor specifically for compression videos

Tags: video, file-compression

The usual zip and 7zip don't do much good when it comes to image or video compression. Anyone knows any good software that is *meant* to compressor videos or images?

Comment: What OS must it run on? How much you're willing to spend when it comes to paid solutions? Is speed (on compress/uncompress) an issue? What video formats are you using, and what minimum compression factor do you need? Keep in mind that several formats already have the videos compressed, so there's not much more anything can do (same as with JPG images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutter Encoder(Free) and HandBrake (Free)are specifically for video compression.

1. [**Shutter Encoder**](https://www.shutterencoder.com/en/) is more feature-rich and compatible. It runs on
   Windows, Mac, Linux and Ubuntu. It supports both the compression of
   video and picture. The supporting file format ranging from VP8, VP9,
   HEVC, H.264 to the old MPEG-2, DVD.
2. [**HandBrake**](https://handbrake.fr/) is an open-source and cross-platform video
   compressor.(Photo files are not supported). It can compress all
   prevalent video formats to MP4, WEBM, and MKV files. There are many
   people complaining about HandBrake's out-of-date UI, but honestly, I
   think it's the most straightforward software that you can use for
   free.

Check the **test data for their compression capability** in [video compressor review](https://www.videoproc.com/video-editor/best-video-compressor.htm).